# How can I initialise a boolean Subject's value to be false?

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I have the subject: `private _hasErrro: Subject<boolean>` that I want to initialise to false, how can I do that?

Comment: `private _hasErrro: Subject<boolean> = new Subject<boolean>(false)`?

Answer (score 2):

You may initialize it as follows, after creating the subject:

```
_hasError.next(false);
```

But if you want to provide an initial value when creating it, you need to use a BehaviorSubject. If it is a `BehaviorSubject`, you may initialize it as follows:

```
private _hasError = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);
```

Comment: This is wrong - you need to declare a new BehaviorSubject - `private _hasErrro: BehaviorSubject<boolean> = new BehaviorSubject(false);`

Comment: use a `BehaviorSubject` for this which is designed specifically to have an initial value

Answer (score 1):

Subjects are created without an initial value. If you want to create a subject with an initial value, you must use a Behavior subject. BS are subjects with an initial value, as defined in RXJS manual:

https://rxjs.dev/guide/subject#behaviorsubject

> It stores the latest value emitted to its consumers, and whenever a
> new Observer subscribes, it will immediately receive the "current
> value" from the BehaviorSubject.

That way, subscriptions will be completed when created with the last emmited value. Your code would be:

```
private _hasErrro = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);
```

Using next with a normal subject in the creator or anywhere in the lifecycle will have a different behavior, as last value won't be stored.